# How do I extract text from Website's Class element with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping

I'm trying to retrieve some text from a website and have tried the following:

```
 Dim inStream As StreamReader
    Dim webRequest As WebRequest
    Dim webresponse As WebResponse
    Try
        webRequest = WebRequest.Create(txtScrape.Text)
        webresponse = webRequest.GetResponse()
        inStream = New StreamReader(webresponse.GetResponseStream())
        txtFormatted.Text = inStream.ReadToEnd()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

However I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.
```

Any assistance would be appriciated or other methods of extracting the text from a class="SummaryCity" like below

```
<span class="SummaryCity">
                thetextIneed, Egypt
        </span>
```

Comment: What's the value of txtScrape.Text you're feeding into the WebRequest.Create?  Is that a  url?

Comment: That's the class name like SummaryCity

Comment: That maybe you’re issue then.  Shouldn’t it be a URL or a uri?